# react-css-modules is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, css-modules, react-css-modules

I want to use react-css-modules, but when I use className `styles.myBtn` in code I get this class `N6OJGonmM2EqyZqImevh` in browser instead of  `myBtn_`.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "curairs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "less-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-css-modules": "^4.7.11",  // !!!
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.58.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

css code

```
.myBtn{
  color: blue;
}
```

Component.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./myBtn.module.css";

const Component=()=>{
  return(
    <div>
      <button className={styles.myBtn}>1234</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Component;
```

How to get `Component_myBtn_XxXx` type class?

Answer (score 0):

If your component file name is `Component` and its code is like this:

```
const Component=()=>{
  return(
   ...
  )
}
```

Assume that you have a `css` file next to the `Component` that its content is:

```
.myBtn{
  color: blue;
}
```

So, the css file should named: `Component.module.css`. Finally, you can use it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Component.module.css";

const Component=()=>{
  return(
    <div>
      <button className={styles.myBtn}>1234</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Component;
```

[image: Edit sharp-chebyshev-hur4b]

Comment: I do exactly the same thing, but I still get a character set instead of a class. It works, but it looks terrible.

I also use the webpack to build the project. Maybe there is a mistake in it?


The part responsible for loading styles:
```
{
        test:/\.(css|less)$/,
        use:[MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
 },
```

Comment: @Mr.Kurosava Please check the `codesandbox` which have been attached.

Comment: @Mr.Kurosava Have your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this in webpack.cofig

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules:{
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        include: /\.module\.css$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader"],
        exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
      },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).